# unexpected exception behaviour in servlets

Tags: java, exception, servlets

I have the below class which loads database details from a properties file. When the file "dao.properties" is missing the class should throw a DAOConfigurationException but instead I am getting

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.clone.dao.DAOFactory.getInstance(DAOFactory.java:19)
    com.clone.controller.register.doPost(register.java:35)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

com.clone.dao.DAOConfigurationException: Properties file dao.properties not found in classpath.
    com.clone.dao.DAOProperties.<clinit>(DAOProperties.java:15)
    com.clone.dao.DAOFactory.getInstance(DAOFactory.java:19)
    com.clone.controller.register.doPost(register.java:35)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

and in subsequent requests I am getting this exeception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.clone.dao.DAOProperties
    com.clone.dao.DAOFactory.getInstance(DAOFactory.java:19)
    com.clone.controller.register.doPost(register.java:35)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

This is my code

```
package com.clone.dao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DAOProperties {
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "dao.properties";
    private static final Properties PROPERTIES = new Properties();
<b> static{
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream propertiesFile = classloader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILE);

        if(propertiesFile==null){
            throw new DAOConfigurationException("Properties file "+PROPERTIES_FILE+" not found in classpath.");
        } 
        try {
            PROPERTIES.load(propertiesFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DAOConfigurationException("Cannot load properties file '"+PROPERTIES_FILE+"'.", e);
        }
    }
</b>
private String specificKey;


    public DAOProperties(String specificKey)
    {
        this.specificKey=specificKey;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) throws DAOConfigurationException {
        String fullKey = specificKey+"."+key;
        String property = PROPERTIES.getProperty(fullKey);
        if(property==null||property.trim().length()==0){
            throw new DAOConfigurationException("Property '"+fullKey+"' is missing in properties file '"+
                                                        PROPERTIES_FILE+"'.");
        }
        return property;
    }

}
```

Guys, please explain whats happening this is a lot confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* throwing a `DAOConfigurationException`:

```
com.clone.dao.DAOConfigurationException: Properties file dao.properties
     not found in classpath.
```

However, that's being wrapped up in an `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` because your `DAOFactory` is trying to use `DAOProperties`. The `DAOProperties` class can't be initialized properly because the static initializer fails, and `ExceptionInInitializerError` is exactly what gets thrown when an static initializer fails.

Perhaps you shouldn't be doing this within the static initializer?

Comment: Thanks for the explination @Jon . After the servlet has thrown  "ExceptionInInitializerError" when I try to acces it again I am getting "NoClassDefFoundError". Shouldn't I get the same exception anytime I access the servlet? The code loads the properties file into memory once hence put in static block.

Comment: @ViswanadhKumarReddyVuggumud: No, that's behaving as described in section 12.4.2 of the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2 - see steps 5 and 11.

Comment: though this is a different question but related, how to handle this type of unexpected runtime exceptions in servlets. By handling I meant not showing users full exception stack in the default way. Specifying a error page in DD for Exception class, is it elegant?

Comment: @ViswanadhKumarReddyVuggumud: Not sure what you mean by "in DD" to be honest - but yes, this does sound like it's a different question.

Comment: I intended to say about web.xml (DD-Deployment Descriptor)